# reading and caching images from a server

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a method to retrieve the images as a property:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:spot.ImageName options:0];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

But now I need to retrieve the images from a server "http://IP/MyService/images/1.png" and cash them to my service.

Comment: There are many questions about performing HTTP requests on this site.  Have you searched for them?

Comment: sure, I performed an HTTP request and this is not my question !

Comment: am asking how to cache them locally in a method and read them

Comment: Yeah your question says "reading and caching" and not just "caching".  Depending on *how* you are retrieving them, there might already be a caching mechanism in place.  So show the HTTP code, not the code that converts a base-64 string into an `UIImage`!

Answer (score 0):

To save the `UIImage` on file system:

```
NSString *documentsDirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.png"];
NSData *binaryImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave);
[binaryImageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

To retrieve the `UIImage` on file system:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Comment: The documents folder is not the place to cache files.

Comment: Why not? Could you please point me to a documented reason for this.

Comment: See [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) and search for "Cache".